# Unable to login to digital ocean ubuntu after some time

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, digital-ocean

I'm working on a laravel project. I hosted it on digital ocean, ubuntu server.

After some days i run the below command
 `$ php artisan serve` on the server, just like I'm on a local host. Since then i could not access the ssh again

Whenever i try to access the ssh i get this error from git bash

**command**

`ssh root@888.00.00.888`

**Error message**

```
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 888.00.00.888 port 22
```

Is there anything I can do except dropping the entire droplet and creating new one.
The website is still in development mode, but what id=f this occur in live version.

Comment: have you restarted the droplet?

Comment: I did not, After many trials I destroy the droplet and create new one